# IIS default document not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, umbraco, default

After I manually set up a virtual directory in IIS on an Umbraco website (that uses MVC), I get a 404 not found error when attempting to browse the URL:

*mydomain/myvirtualdirectory/*

I have the file index.html in the physical directory that the virtual directory points to and I configured IIS to look for index.html as the default document for the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Umbraco was 'intefering'. I needed to add a web.config under the physical folder that the virtual directory points to (the 'ExtensionlessUrlHandler' bit is switching off functionality applied by Umbraco, which was the main problem). This can all be generated via the UI in IIS, or can just be added manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```